# Moving trough Array by using ReadKey()

Tags: c#

In the beginning i will tell that I'm new with C# and Programming. Trying to learn as much as i can alone. 
My first learning project is simple. Moving trough array 10x10 by using "W, S, A, D". It is "game" which is letting user to move his character trough array. The problem is that i want "my character" to move as long as his position will be out of range. So i think i'm trying to make infitive loop which is printing position and lets moving forward. If i'm using for example do{}while(true), position is changing all the time after pressing one key. I'm looking for suggestion how should i construct loop for this kind of "movement". 
I'm attaching my code which is responsible for moving character.

```
int axisx = 0;

int axisy = 0;
var movement = Console.ReadKey();
int[,] level = new int[10, 10];
if (movement.Key.ToString() == "W"){axisy = axisy+1;}
else if (movement.Key.ToString() == "S"){axisy = axisy-1;}
else if (movement.Key.ToString() == "D"){axisx = axisx+1;}
else if (movement.Key.ToString() == "A"){axisx = axisx-1;}
Console.WriteLine("{2} is on position:{0},{1}", axisx, axisy, Player1.getBuilderName());

if (movement.Key == ConsoleKey.Escape)
{
    Console.WriteLine("You pressed Escape, Goodbye");
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use a while(true) loop:

int axisx = 0;
    int axisy = 0;

```
while (true)
{
    var movement = Console.ReadKey();
    if (movement.KeyChar == 'W' || movement.KeyChar == 'w')
    {
        axisy += 1;
    }
    else if (movement.KeyChar == 'S' || movement.KeyChar == 's')
    {
        axisy -= 1;
    }
    else if (movement.KeyChar == 'D' || movement.KeyChar == 'd')
    {
        axisx += 1;
    }
    else if (movement.KeyChar == 'A' || movement.KeyChar == 'a')
    {
        axisx -= 1;
    }
    Console.WriteLine("{2} is on position:{0},{1}", axisx, axisy, Player1.getBuilderName());

    if (movement.Key == ConsoleKey.Escape)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("You pressed Escape, Goodbye");
        break;
    }
}
```

The break; in the ConsoleKey.Escape block will get you out of the loop.
You can also use movement.KeyChar instead of movement.Key.ToString(), strings are immutable in .NET, so every time you do a ToString() you are creating a new string.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, the only thing i made wrong is that my var responsible for movement was out of loop. So stupid mistake :(.

Comment: I've slightly updated the code to be case insensitive and show you the shortcut add and subtract for a variable.

Comment: Thank you so much :). I really appreciate that.

Comment: You should also look at properties as getBuilderName() should probably be a property called BuilderName.  And C# naming conventions dictate that properties and methods should follow PascalCasing